# How to stop alt key with numbers or numeric pad?

Tags: javascript

I want stop alt key with numbers like alt+0146 and etc.
   but if i tried in textbox (alt+0146) it's working, i want all stop.Thanks 
i try many things likes:-

```
$("#typed_data").keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.altKey){
            return false;  // or e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

and also disabled alt like:-

```
if(event.keyCode == 18) {    //alt key
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if any key pressed in combination with `alt` key

```
$("#typed_data").keypress(e => {
    if(e.altKey && e.which) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```